# How to Check if Function Exists in Child (Polymer)

Tags: types, polymer

Parent

```
check() {
  if(typeof this.$.child.function() == 'function') {
    // do something
  }
}
```

How can I check if a child function exists?

This throws

> Uncaught TypeError: this.$.child.function is not a function

Answer (score 1):

Probably the main problem with your code is that you are actually calling the function with the parenthesis `()` and then comparing the result with the string `'function'`.
To check the existence remove the parenthesis:

```
if (this.$.child.function == 'function') { /* ... */ };
```

However the error could also be caused by `this.$.child` being undefined when called. This can happen if you're trying to access your component's static node map (`this.$`) when Polymer hasn't initialised it yet.

The map is accessible in the `ready` lifecycle callback: see [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/dom-template#node-finding).

Comment: That's a valid and very important point - I had to handle a few bugs caused by calling a not $ mapped node (like inside dom-if). Always check if your node map actually contains what you need at the time.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are not using the reserved keyword 'function' as a method name the following should work perfectly fine:

```
check() {
  if(typeof this.$.child.someFunDefinedInChild == 'function') {
  //do work
  }
}
```

Comment: So leaving the parentheses off will not reference a property?

Comment: I'd rather be inclined to check for what @Umbo stated - that the 'function' is not accessible at the time.
Consider: `var a = function() {return 2}
typeof a // "function"
typeof a() // "number"`
So your case should at least not yield an "Uncaught TypeError"